# ImportError: cannot import name 'Template'

Tags: powershell, numpy, pip, python-3.6

```
import numpy as np
from statistics import mean
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[6,7,8,9,10]
m=((mean(x)*mean(y)-mean(x*y))/(mean(x)**2)-(mean(x**2)))
print(m)
```

In the above the(or any other code where I run numpy), Firstly I am getting an input request when running the program. Something like this:

```
PS D:\Codes\Python> python practice.py
Enter no.: 1
Enter: 1
```

which should not happen as values are initialized. I saw in other forums regarding how the file should not be named after a Python module(which you can see, it isn't). Even after that I'm getting error:

```
"C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from string import Template
ImportError: cannot import name 'Template'
```

Can someone please tell me what to do about it?
Edit:
This problem is only powershell centric. The problem is faced when I run program through powershell. It works fine in IDLE.

Comment: You have your module `string.py` that shadows builtin `string`. Rename your module.

Comment: But shouldn't that have happened with IDLE as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a file named "string.py" in your `D:\Codes\Python`.

You can rename it to solve this issue.
You should not name the file to the modules in Python Standard Library.